# Do nothing in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Is there an equivalent to python "pass" in VBA to simply do nothing in the code?

for example:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "Navy Reqs" Then
        ws.Select
        nReqs = get_num_rows
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter
        Selection.AutoFilter
    ElseIf ws.Name = "temp" Then
        pass
    Else
        ws.Select
        nShips = get_num_rows
    End If
Next
```

I get an error here that pass is not defined. Thanks.

Comment: Wow that Python `pass` is the single most ridiculously useless thing I've ever seen.

Comment: Or is it not more like some kind of `continue` statement (C#), i.e. it skips to the next iteration? If so, then simply reword your conditions so that you don't need any no-op code.

Comment: It's useful in python if you have a function or loop that is not yet implemented but you will implement in the future. Instructors use it in their code where they want their students to fill in code often

Comment: Oh wow. So yeah, the VBA equivalent to that is *no code* - actually, a `'not implemented yet` comment would be even better.

Comment: Python is compiled based on indents so the lack of indent throws an error

Comment: Makes sense, I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just remove `pass` and re run the code. VBA will be happy to accept that I believe

Comment: you can also add a comment `'like this` if you want to indicate that you meant to leave it blank (useful for future debugging)

Comment: For this use case tbh, I would have omitted the sheet in the for statement, with <>. It really does depend if this was a place holder, or a sheet he wanted specifically not to include in the statement.

Answer (score 7):

Don't include any statements:

```
Sub qwerty()
    If 1 = 3 Then
    Else
        MsgBox "1 does not equal 3"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Just leave it blank. You can also use a Select statement, it's easier to read.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Navy Reqs":
            '...

        Case "temp":
            'do nothing

        Case Else:
            '...
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 5):

Write code that does what it says, *and says what it does*.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "Navy Reqs" Then
        ws.Select
        nReqs = get_num_rows
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter
        Selection.AutoFilter
    Else If ws.Name <> "temp" Then
        ws.Select
        nShips = get_num_rows
    End If
Next
```

That's all you need. An instruction that means "here's some useless code" does not exist in VBA.

You want comments that say *why*, not *what* - a comment that says `'do nothing` is the exact opposite of that. Don't write no-op code, it's pure noise.

Assuming Python's `pass` works like C#'s `continue` statement and skips to the next iteration, then the VBA equivalent is the one and only legitimate use of a `GoTo` jump:

```
    For ...    
        If ... Then GoTo Skip
        ...
Skip:
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

This code shows an IF test that keeps searching unless it gets a match.

```
Function EXCAT(Desc)
    Dim txt() As String

    ' Split the string at the space characters.
    txt() = Split(Desc)

    For i = 0 To UBound(txt)

        EXCAT = Application.VLookup(txt(i), Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Dept"), 2, False)

        If IsError(EXCAT) Then Else Exit Function

    Next

    ' watch this space for composite word seach
    EXCAT = "- - tba - -"

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I coded in COBOL for many years and the equivalent 'do nothing' statement is `NEXT SENTENCE`.

In VBA, I find myself creating a dummy variable (sometimes a global) `dim dummy as integer` and then when I need that 'do nothing' action in an `If..Then..Else` I put in a line of code:   `dummy = 0`.

Comment: @dippas Actually it is an answer, he suggests a different way to address the problem. Only the last sentence was misleading ... thus I took the freedom to remove it, to make the answer more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Make your own version of "pass" with the following subroutine:

```
Public Sub Pass ()
'This subroutine does nothing except to act as a placeholder
    
End Sub
```

Then just call the subroutine, like:

```
Call Pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a legit question. I want to run a debug routine that stops when a certain critical value is, say, 8, i.e., set break point at x = 8 and then step through line by line. So the following construct is useful:

```
Select Case x
    Case 21
        'do nothing
    Case 8
        'do nothing
    Case 14
        'do nothing
    Case 9
        'do nothing
End Select
```

- Since you can't put a break point on a comment, an actual statement is needed.
- You also can't put a break point on the Case statements because that gets executed every time.

Obviously anything here is OK e.g., `x=x`, but it would be nice to have something formal like `pass`.

But I've been using `x=x`.

Answer (score 1):

Most languages have a "null" or "empty" statement like Python's `pass`. These statements have evolved because they are practically useful, and in some grammars, necessary. For example, as others have suggested, null statements can serve as side-effect free anchors for a debugger.

I use:

```vb
Debug.Assert True
```

Note that if your use case is to set a conditional breakpoint, you may find `Stop` more useful, as in:

```vb
        If targetShape.Type = msoAutoShape Then
            Stop
        End
```

Answer (score 1):

I use 'DoEvents' as no operation lines where I might want a breakpoint for VBA debug. It has the added benefit of always stopping for the 'Esc' key on the keyboard or the pause button in the VBA editor.